# Как закрепить кнопку на изображении?

Tags: android, button, прокрутка, zoom

Есть изображение, которое можно приближать и отдалять (zoom) по типу яндекс и гугл карты. Нужно закрепить кнопку на изображении в одном месте. Раньше был AbsoluteLayout, однако его упразднили и я понимаю почему. Есть альтернатива?

```
df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
scrollPositionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_position);
zoomedRectTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zoomed_rect);
currentZoomTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_zoom);
image = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

// Set the OnTouchImageViewListener which updates edit texts
// with zoom and scroll diagnostics.
image.setOnTouchImageViewListener(new OnTouchImageViewListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMove() {
        PointF point = image.getScrollPosition();
        RectF rect = image.getZoomedRect();
        float currentZoom = image.getCurrentZoom();
        boolean isZoomed = image.isZoomed();
        scrollPositionTextView.setText("x: " + df.format(point.x) + " y: " + df.format(point.y));
        zoomedRectTextView.setText("left: " + df.format(rect.left) + " top: " + df.format(rect.top)
                + "\nright: " + df.format(rect.right) + " bottom: " + df.format(rect.bottom));
        currentZoomTextView.setText("getCurrentZoom(): " + currentZoom + " isZoomed(): " + isZoomed);
    }
});
```

Comment: FloatingActionButton?

Comment: То есть чтобы кнопка привязывалась к определённой точки на изображении и перемещалась при движении этой точки при зуме? Что-то типа маркера на картах?

Comment: Ага, все верно. Что-то вроде маркера.